# How to define a Block Style in an Innerblocks template

Tags: block-editor

I'm building a Innerblocks block template (in PHP) with the following syntax:

```
$template = [
    [
        'core/heading', 
        [
          'level' => 1,
          'content' => 'Example Heading.',
          'align' => 'center'
        ],
    ],
  [
        'core/button', 
        [
          'text' => 'Button 1',
          'align' => 'center',
          'style' => 'outline', // <-- this doesn't work
        ],
    ]
];
```

It mostly works as expected, but I can't determine the syntax to use (or if it is even supported) to define the blocks' style. For example, I would like the Button to use the "Outline" style instead of its default "Fill" style. I've tried as shown above, and also tried something like: `styles => ['name' => 'outline']` to echo the structure of the core/buttons object, but neither work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't determine the syntax to use (or if it is even supported) to
> define the blocks' style. For example, I would like the Button to use
> the "Outline" style instead of its default "Fill" style.

Yes it's supported and the syntax is quite easy.

Excerpt from the [block styles documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-styles/):

> Block Styles allow alternative styles to be applied to existing
> blocks. They work by adding a `className` to the block’s wrapper. This
> `className` can be used to provide an alternative styling for the
> block if the block style is selected. See the  [Getting Started with
> JavaScript
> tutorial](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/javascript/)
> for a full example.
>
> *Example:*
>
> ```
> wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/quote', {
>   name: 'fancy-quote',
>   label: 'Fancy Quote',
> } );
> ```
>
> The example above registers a block style named `fancy-quote` to the
> `core/quote` block. When the user selects this block style from the
> styles selector, an `is-style-fancy-quote` className will be added to
> the block’s wrapper.

So you would just need to add `className` with the value `is-style-<style name>` to the template attributes like so for the `core/button` block and the Outline style (`is-style-outline`):

```php
[
    'core/button',
    [
        'text'      => 'Button 1',
        'align'     => 'center',
        'className' => 'is-style-outline', // add is-style-<style name> to the class list
    ],
]
```

Tried & tested working in WordPress 5.8.1 — see [`style.scss`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/button/style.scss) for other core styles like `is-style-squared`. (that link, however, is for the "master" branch in the GitHub repo, so the styles there may not yet available in the current WordPress release)

Comment: Of course! It never occurred to me to just use the classname — that's really all that distinguishes between style. Thanks!